# Select new with an if statement inside

Tags: c#, .net, linq, if-statement

I have this piece of code that select new some info from the database in my C# project but I only want it to do it if the name is not a certain name so here is the code

```
public List<Info> GetInfo(int id)
{
    var cacheKey = "allinfo-" + id;
    var info = SoftCache.GetData<List<info>>(cacheKey);
    if (info != null)
        return info;

    using (var db = DB.InfoModel)
    {
        info = (from j in db.info_list()

                select new Info
                {
                    InfoName = j.info_name,
                    InfoId = j.info_id,
                    InfoValue = j.info_value,
                }).ToList();
    }

    SoftCache.Add(cacheKey, info, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5), new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0));
    return info;
}
```

What I want is something like

```
if(j.info_name != "BadName"){
    select new Info
    {
        InfoName = j.info_name,
        InfoId = j.info_id,
        InfoValue = j.info_value,
    }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you want. You want to filter by `info_name`, that only records != "BadName" are returned? or you want to return this list only if there is no badname in the table (what your `if` suggests)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a [where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2) statement here:

```
info = (from j in db.info_list()
where j.info_name != "BadName"
select new Info
{
    InfoName = j.info_name,
    InfoId = j.info_id,
    InfoValue = j.info_value,
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use a [where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2) to filter the info as follow:-

```
info = (from j in db.info_list()
where j.info_name != "BadName"
select new Info
{
    InfoName = j.info_name,
    InfoId = j.info_id,
    InfoValue = j.info_value,
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Or by using `Where` extension method

```
var goodNames = 
    db.info_list().Where(info => info.info_name != "Badname")
                  .Select(info => new Info
                  {
                      InfoName = info.info_name,
                      InfoId = info.info_id,
                      InfoValue = info.info_value,
                  })
                  .ToList();
```